# Automate - convert Labels and attach to predefined annotation class

Tags: arcpy, arcobjects

I am developing `pythonaddin` tool which as a result should update/accumulate a predefined *geodatabase annotation standard class*. I am stucked at the point where I believe that `arcpy` has limitations within annotation operations.
With click on the button, I am aiming to show labels with given expresion, to set up data frame scale, convert label to annotation and append it to already predefined annotation.
In the tool, I am able to finalize steps with labels, but not to convert and update existing annotation layer using arcpy.

```
 if layer.supports("LABELCLASSES"):
    for lblClass in layer.labelClasses:
        lblClass.showClassLabels = True
 lblClass.expression ='"%s" & [export.DARST1] & "%s"' % ("<CLR red='255' green='0' blue='0'>", "</CLR>")
 layer.visible = True
 layer.showLabels = True
 self.df.scale = 10000
```

The arcpy methods `arcpy.TiledLabelsToAnnotation_cartography` and then `arcpy.AppendAnnotation_management` do not really help, because they create new annotation features and then trying to append it to predefined annotation is getting hard - makes it difficult and slow, but I will not say imposible. 
Moreover, the last steps I need, would be possible to execute manually (pic below), therefore my assumption is that it can to be performed by adding some lines of code from arcobjects?!
[image: convert labels and attach to existing annotation feature]

Any help if it is possible with python for arcobjects is welcome, otherwise I assume the problem can be solved by working with `ArcObjects` for .NET/C#...

Answer (score 1):

I actually ended up learning and developing the addin using ***ArcObjects in C# .NET*** as I was not certain if it's possible in `arcpy`. With help of [ArcObjects](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/arcobjects-net/conceptualhelp/) reference book as well as the book [Beginning ArcGIS Desktop Development using .NET](https://www.amazon.de/Beginning-ArcGIS-Desktop-Development-using/dp/1118442547/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1516878197&sr=8-1&keywords=Beginning%20ArcGIS%20for%20Desktop%20Development%20using%20.NET) I found the following solution:

- to change a color from text label, the interfaces applied were: `IColor`, `IRgbColor` from ArcObjects
- to change the label text style, it was applied: [`stdole.IFontDisp`](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/arcobjects-cpp/componenthelp/index.html#//001v0000009w000000) ***.NET*** reference
- to set up the label expression, there were applied `IAnnotateLayerProperties` and `ILabelEngineLayerProperties2`, the method: `Expression`
- To convert label to annotation, the interface [`IConvertLabelsToAnnotation`](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/arcobjects-cpp/componenthelp/index.html#//000500000307000000)
- Finally [the snippet code](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/arcobjects-net/conceptualhelp/#/Converting_labels_to_geodatabase_annotation_for_a_single_layer/00010000024r000000/), on which the solution was mostly referenced

Here you can find the code for *ArcMap Add-In Component Button* (note: only field name has changed to `"UEBSCHL"`).

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using ESRI.ArcGIS.ArcMapUI;
using ESRI.ArcGIS.Carto;
using ESRI.ArcGIS.Geodatabase;
using ESRI.ArcGIS.esriSystem;
using ESRI.ArcGIS.Display;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace LabelToAnnotation
{
    public class LabelToAnnotation : ESRI.ArcGIS.Desktop.AddIns.Button
    {   
        static void ConvertLabelsToGDBAnnotationSingleLayer(IMap pMap, int layerIDx, bool featureLinked)
        {
            // call ConvertLabelsTo Annotation Interface and define necessary parameters
            IConvertLabelsToAnnotation pConvertLabelsToAnnotation = new ConvertLabelsToAnnotation() as IConvertLabelsToAnnotation;
            //ITrackCancel parameter
            ITrackCancel pTrackCancel = new CancelTracker() as ITrackCancel;
            //Change global level options for the conversion by sending in different parameters to the next line.
            pConvertLabelsToAnnotation.Initialize(pMap, esriAnnotationStorageType.esriDatabaseAnnotation, esriLabelWhichFeatures.esriSelectedFeatures, true, pTrackCancel, null);

            //get layer according to provided index and obtain dataset
            ILayer pLayer = pMap.get_Layer(layerIDx);
            IGeoFeatureLayer pGeoFeatureLayer = pLayer as IGeoFeatureLayer;
            IFeatureClass pFeatureClass = pGeoFeatureLayer.FeatureClass;
            IDataset pDataset = pFeatureClass as IDataset;


            //color for labels
            IRgbColor rgbColor = new RgbColor() as IRgbColor;
            rgbColor.Red = 255;
            rgbColor.Green = 0;
            rgbColor.Blue = 0;

            IColor lColor = rgbColor as IColor;
            // create font for labels
            stdole.IFontDisp newFont = new stdole.StdFont() as stdole.IFontDisp;
            newFont.Bold = true;
            newFont.Size = 8;

           // create text symbol and set parameters for label style
            ITextSymbol lTxtSymbol = new TextSymbol() as ITextSymbol;
            lTxtSymbol.Color = rgbColor;
            lTxtSymbol.Font = newFont;
            lTxtSymbol.HorizontalAlignment = esriTextHorizontalAlignment.esriTHALeft;
            lTxtSymbol.VerticalAlignment = esriTextVerticalAlignment.esriTVABottom;


            if (pGeoFeatureLayer != null)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(pGeoFeatureLayer.Name);
                //define annotation layer properties collection
                IAnnotateLayerPropertiesCollection annotationLPC = pGeoFeatureLayer.AnnotationProperties;
                annotationLPC.Clear();
                pGeoFeatureLayer.DisplayAnnotation = true;

                //define annotation layer properties, set up label symbology and expression
                //add to collection
                IAnnotateLayerProperties annotateLP = new LabelEngineLayerProperties() as IAnnotateLayerProperties;
                ILabelEngineLayerProperties2 labelELP = annotateLP as ILabelEngineLayerProperties2;
                labelELP.Expression = string.Format("[UEBSCHL]");
                labelELP.Symbol = lTxtSymbol;
                annotationLPC.Add(annotateLP);

                //get feature workspace GDB needed for ConvertLabelsToAnnotation 
                IFeatureWorkspace pFeatureWorkspace = pDataset.Workspace as IFeatureWorkspace;

                Type factoryType = Type.GetTypeFromProgID("esriDataSourcesGDB.FileGDBWorkspaceFactory");
                IWorkspaceFactory wsF = Activator.CreateInstance(factoryType) as IWorkspaceFactory;
                IWorkspace ws = wsF.OpenFromFile(pDataset.Workspace.PathName, ArcMap.Application.hWnd);
                IFeatureWorkspace fws = ws as IFeatureWorkspace;
                IWorkspace2 ws2 = fws as IWorkspace2;

                //set up scale on 1:10000 
                pMap.MapScale = 10000;

                //create base annotation if not exists
                if (ws2.get_NameExists(esriDatasetType.esriDTFeatureClass, "KARTE_LP_DARST1_temp") == false)
                {

                    MessageBox.Show(string.Format("The {0} FeatureClass doesn't exist", pDataset.Name));
                    pConvertLabelsToAnnotation.AddFeatureLayer(pGeoFeatureLayer,"KARTE_LP_DARST1_temp", pFeatureWorkspace,
                    pFeatureClass.FeatureDataset, featureLinked, false, false, true, true, "");

                    //Do the conversion.

                    pConvertLabelsToAnnotation.ConvertLabels();
                    IEnumLayer pEnumLayer = pConvertLabelsToAnnotation.AnnoLayers;
                    //Turn off labeling for the layer converted.
                    pGeoFeatureLayer.DisplayAnnotation = false;

                    //Add the result annotation layer to the map.
                    pMap.AddLayers(pEnumLayer, true);

                }
                //otherwise append labels of selected features on base annotation layer
                else 
                {
                    //append to annotation with layer name: "KARTE_LP_DARST1_temp" 
                    pConvertLabelsToAnnotation.AddFeatureLayer(pGeoFeatureLayer,/*pGeoFeatureLayer.Name + */"KARTE_LP_DARST1_temp", pFeatureWorkspace, pFeatureClass.FeatureDataset, featureLinked, true);
                    pConvertLabelsToAnnotation.ConvertLabels();

                }

                //Refresh the map to update the display.
                IActiveView pActiveView = pMap as IActiveView;
                pActiveView.Refresh();
            }
        }


        public LabelToAnnotation()
        {
        }

        protected override void OnClick()
        {
            //get the mxd document and data frame
            IMxDocument pMxDoc = ArcMap.Application.Document as IMxDocument;
            IMap pMap = pMxDoc.FocusMap;
            //the labels of the first (selected)features layer in data frame will be appended to "KARTE_LP_DARST1_temp"
            ConvertLabelsToGDBAnnotationSingleLayer(pMap, 0 , false);

        }
        protected override void OnUpdate()
        {
            Enabled = ArcMap.Application != null;
        }
    }

}
```